# Monotone increasing solutions of the wave equation

Tags: wave-equation, cauchy-problem, partial-differential-equations

If I have the following PDE;
$${{\partial_t^2 u(t,x)}} - {\partial_x^2 u(t,x)} = 0 \\
 u(0,x) = g(x) \\
{\partial_t u(0,x)} = h(x) $$

Is is true if $g$ and $h$ are monotone increasing then $u(x,t)$ is also monotone increasing?

I started by finding the sub-equations and I found one of the solutions as $$w(t,x) = \int_{x-t}^{x+t} h({\xi}) ~ d{\xi} $$
but this is not necessarily monotone increasing, does this conclude that the statement does not hold? I couldn't find the second solution.
help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) to express the solution as
$$
u(t,x) = \tfrac12 \left[g(x-t) + g(x+t)\right] + \tfrac12\int_{x-t}^{x+t} h(\xi)\,\text d \xi .
$$
It remains to evaluate the sign of
$$
u_x(t,x) = \tfrac12 \left[g'(x-t) + g'(x+t)\right] + \tfrac12 \left[h(x+t) - h(x-t)\right]
$$ when $g'$ and $h'$ are positive. Using the [mean value theorem](https://en./.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there exists $\xi$ such that
$$
h(x+t) - h(x-t) = 2t\, h'(\xi) , \qquad x-t\leq \xi \leq x+t .
$$
Thus, we can conclude for positive times.